# Problema al crear return

Tags: java, intellij-idea

estoy intentando crear un programa que muestra las horas minutos y segundos en formato hh:mm:ss, el problema es que he llegado al punto del return y he de devolver un String con la cadena "0" cuando un numero sea inferior a 10 y necesito hacer el return para que desde su package menu pueda detectarlo.
Este es el codigo:

```
public static int e01Horari(int hores, int minuts, int segons) {
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        if (hores > 23) System.out.println("Hora no vàlida, torna a introduir l'hora");
        hores = lector.nextInt();
        lector.nextLine();
    } while (hores > 23);

    do {
        if (minuts > 59) System.out.println("Minuts no vàlids, torna a introduir els minuts");
        minuts = lector.nextInt();
        lector.nextLine();
    } while (minuts > 59);

    do {
        if (segons > 59) System.out.println("Segons no vàlids, torna a introduir els segons");
        segons = lector.nextInt();
        lector.nextLine();
    } while (segons > 59);

    segons += 1;//segons=segons+1; segons++
    if (segons == 60) {
        segons = 0;
        minuts += 1;
        if (minuts == 60) {
            minuts = 0;
            hores += 1;
            if (hores == 24)
                hores = 0;

        }
    }
    //String que fa la funcio d'afagir un 0 a l'esquerra d'un numero si aquest es inferior a 10
    String hora = "";
    if (hores < 10) hora = "0";
    hora += hores + ":";
    if (minuts < 10) hora += "0";
    hora += minuts + ":";
    if (segons < 10) hora += "0";
    hora += segons;
    System.out.println(hora);
    return hora;

}
```

Que necesito para hacer funcionar el return?
saludos.

Comment: El problema que veo que lo que retornas al final es el String hora, pero tu método e01Horari() retorna un int. 
Es ese tu problema, el error del return?

Comment: @Alex es buena idea que consideres añadir tu respuesta para explicarle al OP lo que ocurre y asi ganar tus puntos merecidos, definitivamente si, es eso lo que falla.

Comment: he hecho lo que me has dicho @Alex y efectivamente era ese el fallo, es más a partir de eso lo he podido modular del todo y he podido quitar la mitad del codigo, muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

he seguido vuestros consejos y he conseguido arreglarlo, muchas gracias por la ayuda, dejo aquí el codigo para el que entre por el mismo problema o lo necesite(el codigo está en catalan pero nada que no arregle google treductor xD):

```
/**
 * metode que permet al usuari l'obtenció de l'horari escollit més un segon al metode menú  
 * @param hores recull un numero de 0 al 23 que equival al nombre d'hores
 * @param minuts recull un numero de 0 al 59 que equival al nombre de minuts
 * @param segons recull un numero de 0 al 59 que equival al nombre de segons
 * @return String equivalent al temps escollit en format hh:mm:ss +1s
 */
public static String e01Horari(int hores, int minuts, int segons) {
    /**
     * condicio que afegeix un numero en funcio dels segons que té, i si arriba al seu máxim afegeix un numero a minuts i/o a hores
     */
    segons += 1;//segons=segons+1; segons++
    if (segons == 60) {
        segons = 0;
        minuts += 1;
        if (minuts == 60) {
            minuts = 0;
            hores += 1;
            if (hores == 24)
                hores = 0;

        }
    }
    //String que fa la funcio d'afagir un 0 a l'esquerra d'un numero si aquest es inferior a 10
    String hora = "";
    if (hores < 10) hora = "0";
    hora += hores + ":";
    if (minuts < 10) hora += "0";
    hora += minuts + ":";
    if (segons < 10) hora += "0";
    hora += segons;
    return hora;

}
```

El problema que había en este codigo era que el metodo que estaba llamando era un tipo "int", es decir, "public static int" y para que el programa funcionase correctamente es un "String"(public static String) como comentaba @Alex. Además he quitado los do/whlies del metodo y los he puesto en otra clase llamada "EntradaDades" para que a la hora de introducir los numeros desde la clase Menu no imprima dos veces el resultado, aparte de introducir seis veces los numeros. Como resultado el metodo es más pequeño y más facil de entender.

Comment: si vas a poner una respuesta, que sea completa, con una explicacion de que pasaba y como se soluciona, no solo el codigo que lo soluciona. lee los enlaces que te deje en tu pregunta. Bienvenido!